# Regular Expression of patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS

Tags: php, android, regex

Does anyone know what the exact regular expression of androids patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS uses?

I need to use the same pattern for PHP. Thank you.

Comment: If you need to validate emails in general and you're just looking for a regular expression and not that specific one for a particular reason, you may want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: I have not yet found a good regex that let's all real emails through. Because of that. Let the user type it twice and if he/she fails twice, it's not meant to be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how **PHP** filter email

```
$Email = "dev@gmail.com";

if (filter_var($Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    echo "Email Is Valid";
else
    echo "Email Isn't Valid";
```

Comment: Does FILTER_VALID_EMAIL have the same regular expression as EMAIL_ADDRESS? I would like to know EMAIL_ADDRESS  regex definition. Thanks

Comment: @nerotech: RegEx don't differ that much from one environment to another, so use what you've got. Or follow the advice of **A Dev** and use `filter_var()`, it is a correct answer to your question.

Comment: @nerotech, they both use same standard so, don't worry about result

Answer (score 0):

```
 public boolean checkEmail(EditText editText) {
    boolean emailIsValid = editText.getText().toString().matches("[^.]?([a-zA-Z0-9]+[._]?)*[-]?([a-zA-Z0-9]+[._]?)*[a-zA-Z0-9][@][a-z0-9]*[-]?[a-z0-9]*[.][a-z0-9]*[.]?[a-z0-9]*");
    return !(android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(editText.getText().toString()).matches()) || !emailIsValid;
}
```

if it returns true then it is not a valid email.

Answer (score 0):

checkEmail method will return true, if email text is valid.

```html
public final static Pattern EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(

            "^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
                    + "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                    + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
                    + "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                    + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
                    + "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$");


    public static boolean checkEmail(String email) {
        return EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN.matcher(email).matches();
    }
```

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: TLD list https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db valid/invalid addresses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples regex for RFC822 email address http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html